# Should RVM automatically change gemsets based on .ruby-gemset?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I updated RVM and started switching from `.rvmrc` to `.ruby-gemset` and, where necessary, `.ruby-version`.

However, so far, when I change into a directory with `.ruby-gemset`, it doesn't automatically start using the correct one as it would with `.rvmrc`.

**Is it supposed to work the same way?**

I'm using RVM 1.20.5.

Comment: Yes it is supposed to do so. Update your question with the contents of `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset`. And also the output of the `rvm gemset list`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RVM detects `.ruby-version` and only if it is present it will read `.ruby-gemset`.

RVM does not reads `.ruby-gemset` when `.ruby-version` is not available.

You could try `.ruby-version` *(editted from `current`)*:

```
default
```

Comment: That was my problem - no `.ruby-version` file. Although putting `current` in `.ruby-version` seems to have no effect. Putting something like `ruby-2.0.0-p0` in `.ruby-version` does work.